# Hilbert space and a linear map

Tags: hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ is a Hilbert space. Let $f:H \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is linear and that there is a constant $C$ such that $|f(x)| \leq C ||x||$ for all $x \in H$

Suppose {$e_n$} is a complete orthonormal set for $H$.

show that

y=$\Sigma e_n \overline{f(e_n)} \in H$ and that $f(x)=<x, y>$ for all $x \in H$

I have shown that $f$ is continuous since

$|f(x)-f(y)|=|f(x-y)|\leq C||x-y||<C\delta$ by taking $\delta=\epsilon/C$

What are the next steps?

Comment: Are we to assume $y = \sum e_n \overline{f(e_n)}$?

Comment: yes. I omit that sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show that $\sum\overline{f(e_n)}e_n\in H$. To this
end you have to prove that $\sum_n|f(e_n)|^2<\infty$. This will require
using $|f(x)|\le C\|x\|$.

Comment: I got $||y|| = \Sigma_n |f(e_n)|^2$ using that if {$e_n$} is a complete orthonormal set for $H$ iff for all $x \in H$
$||x||^2= \Sigma_n |<x, e_k>|^2$. I'm not quite sure why $ \Sigma_n |f(e_n)|^2< \infty$